# Availability of Symbols for Entity Framework 5

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to debug code interacting with Entity Framework 5 (under Visual Studio Express for Web 2012) by stepping into an EF method, however it appears that the symbols for EF5 are not available on the Microsoft symbol server.  I found a thread in early 2012 that seemed to indicate that the symbols were not there and weren’t going to be added:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2bd65e92-d21c-4d69-9e7b-5fe54122926f/

but I think this predates the final release of EF5.  In short: **is it (still) true that the symbols aren’t available from Microsoft’s symbol server, and (assuming so) is there another way to obtain the symbols for EF5 and use them within VSEW 2012?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No symbols were published for EF 5, see the article you linked and the following from the EF team,

http://entityframework.codeplex.com/discussions/447345

Having said that you have a few options:

- Get reflector which will decompile ef on the fly and let you step
  into it (i dont think this works on express editions)
- Download the EF source from CodePlex and build it yourself
- Ask a specific question about the issue you are seeing with EF